# Generalization with plural versus with definite article

Tags: grammar, definite-articles, rhetoric

I was studying the usage of definite article in Arabic and I realized I am not on firm grounds in English either.

With respect to either grammar or rhetoric, are there nuances between the following usages:

> Women do not cheat without a good reason.

versus

> A woman does not cheat without a good reason.

(My guess: The former sounds more like a statistical observation, say the huge majority act as such; the latter sounds as if it defines the prototype woman, even though there will be exceptions.)

---

**Addendum I**

A correspondent brought up a good point. The plural usage---to a certain degree, maybe subconsciously---brings men into the picture: women act as such --> men, not necessarily so; but the latter usage does not have such a connotation.

Comment: These are [generic noun phrases](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), and they have special grammar and affordances. Articles have no meaning in English; they're just part of the machinery, and generic NPs are some of the machines that use them.

Comment: Your title makes no sense to me, nor does your addendum. You miss the definite article from the first sentence of your question, suggesting that you are not a native English speaker, in which case you would be advised to refer to the many questions on article here and on English Language Learners.

Comment: I disagree with your addendum.  Both sentences seem to be stating that women, rather than men, have this trait. That is what makes them both generic statements. They both also feed on stereotype.  It might be nice if you chose/added some different sentences, so I could ignore the idea that only men cheat with abandon.

Comment: I also disagree with John Lawler's notion that articles have no meaning.  The indefinite article conveys numerical meaning (among other meaningful things). The definite article conveys specificity (ditto on the meaningful things).  Yes, they are a chore to define, but that hardly "means" they have no meaning. Whether the words have direct translations in other languages is a different matter, even if their meaning can generally be conveyed in other ways than direct translation.

Comment: In addition, there is a tendency among non-native speakers, from languages that do not have them, to "decorate" their language with erroneous articles. I find myself twisting into knots trying to find meaning in these structures.  I could say that their errors have no meaning, but that would be too simple.  In addition, I often find that a missing article makes a phrase sound like slang I am unaware of. The example that comes to mind is "I eat apple", which was, in fact, brought to my attention by a student who wanted to illustrate that "I knew what he meant". Did I?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the statistical nature of the plural use, though I would lean toward calling it "generalization", but would say that the singular use sounds, with nuance, to be a reaction to a particular woman's actions. This is a particular use of the indefinite article in that it generalizes things, but allows for number.  The definite article makes things specific, which does not seem to be part of this discussion. Both "Tuesdays" and "a Tuesday" count as generalizations, though the former sounds like a repetitive event, while the latter sounds like you are asking for a single availability (both among many).

Are Tuesdays good for you?

versus

Is a Tuesday good for you?

The difference between the use of the indefinite article in the second half of the sentences is worth some attention, as it turns an uncountable noun into a countable one. Still a nuance more than any firm difference in meaning.

Comment: "would say that the singular use sounds, with nuance, to be a reaction to a particular woman's actions" is a good point.